# VSCode (with oh-my-zsh) prints an extra character after each command

Tags: visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I'm experimenting with VSCode and MSYS2 (on Windows 10), there is not reason for me to use MSYS2 other than having a C compiler. While using it, I found out that I can use bash provided by MSYS2 on windows, and zsh too, so I decided to use ohmyzosh because it had themes. I created a profile in VSCode for ohmyzosh, set it to default, and now whenever I use a command, VSCode prints "\" after the output. Like:

```
## Start of terminal

\➜  folder ls 
somefile.txt
\➜  folder
```

It is expected to be without the backslashes, just like how it is when I use an external terminal. (Windows Terminal)

Note: This backslash is shown then removed after a second if the theme that I use contains a clock. It doesn't get removed automatically if the theme is static.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using WSL instead of MSYS2. This didn't solve the issue but instead gave the correct results; The backslashes don't appear while using oh-my-zsh anymore, and that's what I needed. I also found it to be easier to compile C using WSL, so I don't have to use MSYS2 anymore.